# Global maxima and global minima.

Tags: derivatives, maxima-minima

> Find global maxima  and global minima of
>   $$f(x)=3(x-2)^{\frac{2}{3}}-(x-2)$$
>   over the interval $[0,20]$.

**My input:** Derivative vanishes at $x=10$ and left neighborhood gives positive derivative  and right neighborhood gives negative derivative . Therefore $x=10$ is the value where function attains global maxima.(Correct me here if i write something wrong). And i am not able to figure out the global minima. Need help.  I saw graph of this function at Desmos but there is a peak at $2$ i am not able to understand that too. At peak we have derivative not defined ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrong, here $x=10$ is not a global maximum point.

Notice that the function $f$ is continuous in $I=[0,20]$, but it is not differentiable at $2$. So, by  [Fermat's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_(stationary_points)),  if $x_0$ is a global extremum of $f$, then one of the following is true:

- $x_0$  is a boundary point of $I$ (i.e. $x_0=0$ or $x_0=20$);
- $x_0$ is a non-differentiable point in $I$ (i.e. $x_0=2$);
- $x_0$ is stationary point in $I$, (i.e. $x_0=10$).

So you should evaluate $f$ at $0$, $2$ and $20$ and compare those values with $f(10)$ ($10$ is the stationary point that you have already found).

Comment: Please elaborate it to me sir. Looking at graph it seems that at $x=20$ we have global minima ?

Comment: See this corollary of Fermat's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_(stationary_points)#Corollary

Comment: At f(0) there is maximum value and f(2) we have minima right ? I evaluated all those value and found the at 0 we have global max. Did i do it right ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

you are correct, the Maximum will be attained for $x=10$ gives $$f(10)$$
the Minimum for $x=2$ this gives $$f(2)=0$$

Comment: If we take derivative we have (x-2) in the denominator. Don't you think at 2 it will be  not defined ?

Comment: the derivative yes, but $f(2)=0$ for $x=2$ we have that the derivative doesn't exists